# Kibana role management on custom plugins

Tags: kibana

I developed several kibana plugins.
Then I register their features by using xpack_main.
And I created a new role for one plugin and used this.
But all custom plugins are shown at the navigation menu.
When i clicked the item, only privileged item is working and others are not working.
I want to display only the privileged item on the menu.